# Interpretation of Regression coefficient with percentages

Tags: regression, interpretation, percentage

I am working on price prediction problem a Real Estate space. I fit a regression model where the independent variable is calculated as percentage change and dependent variable is expressed as a percentage. Dependent variable Vt is Vacancy rate.

Sample

```
Vt = 6.393952
            6.331960
            6.286561
            6.154322
            6.237609
            ...   
            5.821563

Vt = b0 + b1 * Rt


                       coef            
----------------------------
Intercept             0.0456        
Rent_Change          -0.7921
```

The interpretation of Rent_Change here is Vt decreases by about 80% with 1 unit (1%) increase in rent change. Is that correct? This doesn't seem to be what I would expect. Negative relationship makes sense, however, the magnitude seems too high.

Comment: Its difficult to answer without knowing what Vt stands for.

Comment: @elexhobby Its vacancy rate, expressed as percentage.

Comment: Your estimate says a change in `Rent_Change` of $1$ is associated with a change in $V_t$ of  $-0.79.$ For instance, that would alter a value of $V_t$ equal to $6.00\%$ to $6.00 -0.79\% = 5.21\%.$  That isn't anywhere near 80%!  In most situations you can be sure of your interpretation by graphing the data and the fit.

Comment: ah, I was thinking 0.79*100 as the coefficient, but 0.79 is already expressed in percentages.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.